# Data type for bounding box in MongoDB and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I am looking at storing an entry in MongoDB that refers to a route, that is stored in an external file, but has the bounding box of that route in the database. I am not sure whether I should be using a Polygon for this or whether there is a better data type? The main thing that needs to be considered is that this will be used in searches. For example, a search where a route is an area. The start points and end points aren't sufficient, since they don't necessarily represent the extent (a track can finish where it started, for example).

I am using a [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) and [mongoose-geojson-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-geojson-schema)

So far, I have something like:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongooseGeoJSON = require('mongoose-geojson-schema');

const hikeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    when: Date,
    startPoint: mongoose.Schema.Types.Point,
    endPoint: mongoose.Schema.Types.Point,
    boundingBox: //Not sure?
});
```

**update**: For now I am just going to use the Polygon type, failing any better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a note in case you end up here this is what I used (mongoose 3.6) - still using a polygon but then that's the right way i suspect:

```
Place.where('location').intersects().geometry({
    type: "Polygon",
    coordinates: [[
        [ minLongitude, minLatitude ],
        [ minLongitude, maxLatitude ],
        [ maxLongitude, maxLatitude ],
        [ maxLongitude, minLatitude ],
        [ minLongitude, minLatitude ]
    ]]
}).exec()
```